# R- rbind duplicated rows

Tags: r, list, rbind

I need to extract all numbers from a string and save them in one field as a list.
My code is:

```
library(stringr)
d<-data.frame(dir='a', x=1)

DIR<-"PJE INDEPENDENCIA 96 5"
X <- str_extract_all(DIR,"\\(?[0-9]+\\)?")[[1]]
d<-rbind(d, data.frame(dir=DIR ,  x=X))
```

But I get:

```
> d
                     dir  x
1                      a  1
2 PJE INDEPENDENCIA 96 5 96
3 PJE INDEPENDENCIA 96 5  5
```

While I need to get:

```
                     dir  x
1                      a  1
2 PJE INDEPENDENCIA 96 5 96,5
```

I tried adding list, but didn't work.
How can I avoid rbind generating all possible combinations?
Thanks

Comment: You could try `rbind(d, data.frame(dir=DIR , x=I(list(X))))` or you could paste the `X` together ie. `rbind(d, data.frame(dir=DIR , x=toString(X)))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `d<-rbind(d, data.frame(dir=DIR ,  x=toString(X)))`

Comment: Thanks, but can you tell me what is the difference with as.character? and why with as.character I couldn't do the same?

Comment: `as.character` converts its argument to character; `toString` converts its argument to character *and* concatenates the elements.